# python gzip module sometimes writes trailing bytes

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, gzip

I am currently trying to process larger text files where I read them from a gzipped file, process the text and write the processed text to bunch of new gzipped files. My solution to this is basically what is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580517/python-multiprocessing-write-to-single-gzip-in-parallel). In short I do the following:

```py
import gzip
import multiprocessing as mp

def process_text(inqueue, outqueue):
   while True:
      textblock = inqueue.get()
      if textblock:
         subblocks = dict()
         # process and split textblock
         compressed_subblocks = dict()
         for id, subblock in subblocks:
            compressed_subblocks[id] = gzip.compress(
               bytes(stream.getvalue(), 'utf-8'),
               compresslevel = 9
            )
         outqueue.put(compressed_subblocks)
      
      else:
         outqueue.write(dict())
         break


def write_files(outqueue, outfiles, active_text_processors):
   while True:
      compressed_subblocks = outqueue.get()
      if compressed_subblocks:
         for id, compressed_subblock in compressed_subblocks.items():
            outfiles[id].write(compressed_subblock)
            outfiles[id].flush()
       
      else:
         active_text_processors -= 1
         if not active_text_processors:
             break
      
#initialize outputfiles
outfiles = {
   id: open(f'file_{if}.gz', 'wb') for id in ids
}

# initialize queues and start processors and writer
# I know this would be much better with a Pool but this code
# but i didn't come around rewriting it yet
processing_threads = 4
inqueue, outqueue = mp.Queue(), mp.Queue()
processes = [
   mp.Process(
      target = process_text.
      args = [inqueue, outqueue]
   ) for i in range(processing_threads)
]

writer = mp.Process(
   target = writer,
   args = [outqueue, outfiles, processing_threads]
)

buffersize = 250000
with gzip.open(file_to_process, 'rt') as infile:
   lines = []
   for line in infile:
      lines.append(line)
      if len(lines) == buffersize:
         inqueue.put(buffersize)

# waiting for writer process to complete
writer.join()
for outfile in outfiles.values():
   outfile.close()
```

This works fine for most of the time however for some files when I try to gunzip them I get

```
gzip: infile.txt.gz: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
```

And specifically with the Python `gzip` module I get

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'^\x9f')
```

I figured that this might be a bug in `gzip.py` as of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928560/how-can-i-work-with-gzip-files-which-contain-extra-data). However, this does not solve my problem as I use an external python tool that uses gzip to read the files I produces and that now fails due to the trailing garbage. I am therefore looking for a solution to prevent Python from writing these trailing bytes but was unsuccessful. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind does not seem to be an issue with the code. I discovered that the names of the effected files occur in more than one file to process. Thus, running concurrent instances of the code to speed up computation those files get written to from more than one process which results in some trailing bytes. I am actually surprised that they are not corrupted and no error was being thrown from any of the process instances. Anyway, code seems to work just a usual concurrency issue.